# Auto start Gradle Daemon in build container

Tags: java, docker, jenkins, gradle, gradle-daemon

I have a Jenkins Server running which uses the Docker and Cloud plugins to allow for spawning of a new container from a specified image as required. Inside this container I build a Java project which uses the Gradle Daemon. Basically it starts the daemon when the build starts. Is there a way to forcibly start the daemon such that I can do it when the container starts to this can be pre-started.